# Setting Id not working when iterating through

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
var i = 0;

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <text>

    $('#jp_audio_' + i).attr("id", "#jp_audio_@item.Id")
    i++;

    </text>
}
```

i++ seems to stop it from working. If i++ is not there then it does set `#jp_audio_0` to new id, but I need to set all of the ids to new value, not just first one. Any ideas why?

Html with i++ (Id's not being set to new value);

```
<audio id="jp_audio_0" preload="metadata" src="http://localhost:6060/Music/StreamPublishedSongs/95"></audio>
<audio id="jp_audio_1" preload="metadata" src="http://localhost:6060/Music/StreamPublishedSongs/96"></audio>
```

without i++ in code (first 1 being set actually working);

```
<audio id="#jp_audio_96" preload="metadata" src="http://localhost:6060/Music/StreamPublishedSongs/95"></audio>
<audio id="jp_audio_1" preload="metadata" src="http://localhost:6060/Music/StreamPublishedSongs/96"></audio>
```

Comment: How about an if/then to determine what `i` is and when to stop iterating? This would continue forever if you don't stop it.

Comment: I have 2 items in Model, so it's only going to go through the foreach loop twice and then stop. So it won't keep going on forever.

Comment: What are the first and last numbers? Why do you have to iterate it versus just "hard coding" the two numbers? Where do the numbers come from?

Comment: first number is 0, because i is 0, last number will be 1 because I have 2 items in model (this just for example, I have unknown amount in my code which means I cant hard code)

Comment: Does my answer below (or a version of it) work for you then? Updated to iterate only 2 items.

Comment: I can't use a for loop in my foreach loop which is why I was trying to iterate without it.

With your answer it goes to first item, sets 0 and 1 both to 96, then it goes to second item and sets them again to 97 (97 because new @item.id)

Comment: Is i a JavaScript variable or C# variable?

Comment: Can you just add a value to the item.Id to get what you need for the id?

Comment: Js variable (i think). Also not sure what you mean by add value to item.id

Comment: So your foreach loop is within a script tag?

Comment: Have you tried putting a semi-colon at the end of `$('#jp_audio_' + i).attr("id", "#jp_audio_@item.Id")`?

Comment: Yes, it is in script tag, it is in an MVC view. Should have put that in question. putting semi-colon makes no difference

Comment: Do you specifically want the variable to be a  javascript variable. Can you try: @{int i = 0;}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <text>

    $('#jp_audio_' + @i).attr("id", "#jp_audio_@item.Id")
    @i++;

    </text>
}

Comment: It converts it to number. So @i++ is giving me error invalid left hand side in assignment

Comment: @sitBy for i++ try @{i++;} with my code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert your variables to C#:

```
@{
int i = 0;
} 
@foreach (var item in Model)
 { 
<text> 
$('#jp_audio_' + @i).attr("id", "#jp_audio_@item.Id"); 
@{i++;} 
</text> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something more like this...I'm using pure JS, so you'll have to apply to your situation (MVC):

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $('#jp_audio_' + i).attr("id", "#jp_audio_@item.Id")
}
```

Here `i` would start at 0 and then end at 1. Not sure where you need to start and top though.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the structure of the 'Model' object, it's hard to tell what's going on. Here's a jQuery example outputting the values the way I think you want them. Notice how I've structured the object so that I can access the items' properties via Model.items in the loop.

```js
$(function(){
  var Model = {
        items: [{
            id: 'ID-1234',
            name: 'foo'
        }, {
            id: 'ID-4567',
            name: 'bar'
        }]
    },
    i = 0
  ;
  for( item in Model.items) {
    $('#jp_audio_' + i).attr("id", "#jp_audio_"+Model.items[i].id);
    
    // output some text so we can see the IDs we're changing
    $('.container').append("#jp_audio_"+Model.items[i].id+'<br/>');
    i++;
  } 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <audio id="jp_audio_0" preload="metadata" src="#"></audio>
  <audio id="jp_audio_1" preload="metadata" src="#"></audio>
</div>
```